# BlueZ: LE secure pairing using Elliptical Curve Diffie-Hellman from command line

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, diffie-hellman

One of the main features of Bluetooth v4.2 is LE secure connections, where Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) is used for the key agreement protocol. As of BlueZ v5.26, support for LE secure connections has been added as follows:-

"*BlueZ 5.26 is the first release with support for Blueooth 4.2 features. Perhaps the most notable one of these is Low Energy Secure Connections which will require a 3.19 or newer kernel.*"[1]

Is there a way to test ECDH pairing through the command line? if not, what is the easiest way to test this?

I'm using BlueZ v5.38 on kernel 3.19 but I can't figure out how to do this.

[1] http://www.bluez.org/release-of-bluez-5-26/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, the secure connections feature using ECDH can be verified by performing pairing (using bluetoothctl) between two Bluetooth v4.2 devices and observing the output through btmon. Look for HCI Event: Link Key Notification and observe the Key type. If it shows P-256, then Secure Connections feature is verified. If it shows P-192, then it is using Secure Simple Pairing (SSP).

Additional background on this can be found in the Bluetooth Core Specification v4.2 in Vol 1, Part A, Section 5.1: Security Architecture.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Does this apply to LE Secure Connections? or is it just for Secure Connections feature of classic Bluetooth?

Comment: For LE Secure Connections, both linux systems should be configured to be in single mode (LE only). This can be done via btmgmt. Then, set the IO capabilities to KeyboardDisplay or DisplayYesNo and then perform the pairing normally. At btmon, you should look out for the event "Pairing DHKey Check". This PDU is only used for LE Secure Connections. Please see Bluetooth Spec v4.2 Vol. 3 Part H Section 3.5.7 for more info. Other events generic to both BREDR and LE SC are "Pairing Public Key" and to look out for the SC flag under "Authentication requirement"